# Nuke Python save tool settings in nuke script file

Tags: python, nuke

What is the best way to save random user tool settings in a nuke script file? I searched around online a fair bit and found nothing regarding this topic which I found hard to believe.

At the end of the day my goal is to save some random tool data on in the file and additionally save some other data specifically on a few nodes in the graph. I was unable to find info on either.

Answer (score 0):

Save it on the root! Create a custom knob of any type, set it to "hidden" and store it on the Root of the script:

`nuke.Root()`

The Root is just a fancy knob, so most any command that works on a node can also work on the Root.

Comment: This is F"!%"!£ insane!!! Is there really no way to save custom data on gizmo/nodes ?!?!?!? fk me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I think you misunderstand - you can absolutely store arbitrary data on a node, the same way you can on the root. The Root is a Node in nuke python, so you can add knobs just as a regular node. To store arbitrary data, make a hidden text knob and pickle to/from it.

Comment: Excepy that if I make combo box and set options dynamically during runtime, when I save  nuke script/load you get an error because even tho current option get stored, the list of available options don't and it crashes nuke script load routine. Even doing before/after save logic to presave/pre-load/configure gizmos fail.

Comment: ahhh i think i get it. probably better to make knob manually through the normal method with a dummy list that will remain in the file. then do your update in an onScriptLoad, possibly wiping the list and replacing it with the one you want. you might have to store the current item in another hidden field with an onKnobChange callback as well